# How do I show a custom error message instead of 'No applicable approval process was found'? Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, approval-process, error-messages

I would like to show a custom error message to override the standard Salesforce message of 'No applicable approval process was found.' The error message is due to the user not checking a box, which causes the process to fail. It would be better to have a message that would tell the user why the process is failing and to simply check the checkbox in order to fix it themselves.

Could someone help point me in the right direction of a possible visualforce page that could accomplish this?